# When `GC` will be triggered when an `OutOfMemoryException` is caught?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am having an java package, which connects with a database and fetches some data. At some rare case, I am getting heap memory exception, since the fetched query data size is exceeding the java heap space. Increasing the java heap space is not something the business can think for now.

Other option is to catch the exception and continue the flow with stopping the execution. ( I know catching `OOME` is not a good idea but here only me local variables are getting affected). My code is below:

```
private boolean stepCollectCustomerData() {
     try {          
          boolean biResult = generateMetricCSV(); 
     } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {         
        log.error("OutOfMemoryError while collecting data ");            
        log.error(e.getMessage());      
        return false; 
     }
        return true;
    }

private boolean generateMetricCSV(){

        // Executing the PAC & BI cluster SQL queries.
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connectionURL", "username", "password")) {

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            for (RedshiftQueryDefinition redshiftQueryDefinition: redshiftQueryDefinitions){
                File csvFile = new File(dsarConfig.getDsarHomeDirectory() + dsarEntryId, redshiftQueryDefinition.getCsvFileName());
                log.info("Running the query for metric: " + redshiftQueryDefinition.getMetricName());
                try( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = createPreparedStatement(connection,
                        redshiftQueryDefinition.getSqlQuery(), redshiftQueryDefinition.getArgumentsList());
                     ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                     CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));) {

                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        resultSet.beforeFirst();
                        log.info("Writing the data to CSV file.");
                        writer.writeAll(resultSet, true);
                        log.info("Metric written to csv file:  " + csvFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        filesToZip.put(redshiftQueryDefinition.getCsvFileName(), csvFile);
                    } else {
                        log.info("There is no data for the metric " + redshiftQueryDefinition.getCsvFileName());
                    }
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    log.error("Exception while generating the CSV file: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }  catch (SQLException e){
            log.error("Exception while creating connection to the Redshift cluster: " + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

We are getting exception in the line `"ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()"` in the later method and i am catching this exception in the parent method. Now, i need to make sure when the exception is caught in the former method, is the GC already triggered and cleared the local variables memory? (such as connection and result set variable) If not, when that will be happen?

I am worried about the java heap space because, this is continuous flow and I need to keep on fetching the data for another users.

The code that i have provided is only to explain the underlying issue and flow and kindly ignore syntax, etc.., I am using `JDK8`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OOM is the result of a GC run failing to free up any more memory, so it happens *after* GC, so no, local variables have not been cleared. Once you catch the exception, the local variables may have gone out of scope, so they are now eligible for GC. The next GC run, which is likely to happen very soon, will free the newly released objects.

Comment: Yes i do agree. "in next GC run", when it will be happening? You mean to say, it will be triggered automatically when java heap is almost full? or any GC schedule? Or it will be cleared (memory freed up ) once the exception is caught?

Comment: Memory is *already* full, which is why you got OOM. Very likely, the very next attempt to allocate memory will trigger another GC run.

Comment: memory is not full actually, lets say our current heap memory is 1.5 GB and then you try to create an object with memory 0.5GB (1.7GB is max heap memory), in this case the jvm wont have 1.6999GB (something like) and throw this error. My understanding JVM wont allocated any memory and inside the catch block, the heap memory will be still 1.5GB only.

Comment: Also, you mean to say GC will trigger when there is not enough memory (in a hope to get some memory free) and if not finally OOME will be thrown.

Comment: I mean that GC will run when system fails to allocate memory. You're right, if the attempted allocation has large, you're not entirely out of memory yet, just don't have enough for *that* object, which is why I said "likely". The OOM could have been the result of a `new Integer` attempt, in which case you are entirely out of memory, so any other attempt would likely try GC again, in the hope that something has been freed by now.

Comment: It is *guaranteed* that GC has *already* run *before* an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html]).

Comment: So based on the above comments, i can confirm there is no need for me to worry whether the GC is going to run in the catch block. GC will run on demand for next case. Since, this is the only place where i am getting OOME, the current implementation will work good.

Comment: Hang on. GC does not clear local variables. However as you are using try-with-resources, you are guaranteed that those resources are closed after the completion of the try-with-resources statement, i.e. after all the `catch` blocks following it. This has nothing to do with garbage collection. The objects concerned become eligible for GC when the method exits.

Comment: @user207421 The link is broken. How about in case when it is unable to create native thread?

Comment: @user207421 actually, the objects become eligible to garbage collection after their last use, which may be much earlier than you think. But it’s not guaranteed that a garbage collection cycle gets every eligible object. In practice, it depends on how much effort the JVM’s code optimizer has spent on a method, whether object’s referenced by local variables (from a source code’s point of view) are still considered reachable.